# Need driver to initialise before every test in c#/Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have an class separate to the tests which initiates the Firefox driver:

```
public static class DriverContext
{
    public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public static void Initialize()
    {
       Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     }
 }
```

I have a stack of step definition classes for my feature files
When i run the feature files i want each scenario/feature to call this class, open the browser and navigate to a webpage.

How do i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't indicate what framework you use.

So, taking SpecFlow as an example, you can use hooks such as `[BeforeScenario]` or `[BeforeFeature]` and call the initialise method there.

You might then want to use `[AfterScenario]` to close the browser windows after each run.

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks

Comment: HI. I tried that. It opens a ff window but it doesnt go to the website or run the tests       public abstract class Hook
    {
        [Binding]
        public class HookInitialize
        {

            [BeforeFeature]
            public static void TestStart()
            {
                DriverContext.Initialize();
            }

        }
    }
}

Comment: @massjobs well, without seeing your steps code it's hard to say.  You could be missing a reference etc.